# how to alter disable or enable trigger with ORACLE JOB SCHEDULER

Tags: sql, oracle11g

in a job_action of a JOB SCHEDULER i have the following SQL

```
'BEGIN
       ALTER TRIGGER AFTERIUDSETTLEMENTS DISABLE;
       ALTER TRIGGER AFTERIUDLIQUIDATIONSDETAILS DISABLE;
       UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS A SET INLD = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIQUIDATIONSDETAILS LD WHERE A.CUSTOMERID = LD.CUSTOMERID AND A.ID = LD.APPOINTOFCAID AND A.KINDCONTROLID = LD.KINDCONTROLID);
       UPDATE APPOINTSOFCAS A SET INSD = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SETTLEMENTS S WHERE A.CUSTOMERID = S.CUSTOMERID AND A.ID = S.APPOINTOFCAID AND A.KINDCONTROLID = S.KINDCONTROLID);
COMMIT;
       ALTER TRIGGER AFTERIUDSETTLEMENTS ENABLE;
       ALTER TRIGGER AFTERIUDLIQUIDATIONSDETAILS ENABLE;                            
END;'
```

but after run the job failed with thow following error:

```
ORA-06550: γραμμή 2, στήλη 29:
```

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:

```
 begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
 <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
 συνέχεια close current delete fetch lock insert open
 rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
οριστική διαγραφή
```

is possible to disable or enable trigger in JOB SCHEDULER?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ALTER statement is DDL, which means it can't be done within the scope of a PL/SQL block without using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/executeimmediate_statement.htm#LNPLS01317).

This is fairly unusual, it means that your triggers are disabled for every session so if anything else were to happen they won't trigger any changes. It's possible but this just feels wrong.

You can also do your two updates within a single statement, which will be more efficient.

```
begin

   execute immediate 'alter trigger afteriudsettlements disable';
   execute immediate 'alter trigger afteriudliquidationsdetails disable';

   update appointsofcas a 
      set inld = ( select count(*) 
                     from liquidationsdetails ld 
                    where a.customerid = ld.customerid 
                      and a.id = ld.appointofcaid 
                      and a.kindcontrolid = ld.kindcontrolid )
        , insd = ( select count(*) 
                     from settlements s 
                    where a.customerid = s.customerid 
                      and a.id = s.appointofcaid 
                      and a.kindcontrolid = s.kindcontrolid );

   commit;

   execute immediate 'alter trigger afteriudsettlements enable';
   execute immediate 'alter trigger afteriudliquidationsdetails enable';

end;
/
```

Comment: <Nitpick> I'd add an exception handler that re-enables the triggers in case the update raises an exception </Nitpick>